# Python - SSIS Package Install Confirmation

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis

How to check if my sql server has python installed on it or not ? An SSIS Package that my client will run will have a python script on it.

Is there a way to check if python is installed on that Server or not ?

Comment: ask your sysadmin to confirm that for you.

Comment: @rvphx No option to check from our end ?

Comment: I would love to hear if you can come up with that. Not joking.